# Wordpress form submit: do $_REQUEST and form POST method work with WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

I have a hand-built (HTML/PHP) site that I would like to replicate on Wordpress. The site includes a form which sends the user input to a 3rd party server which returns a price quote which then gets displayed.
The structure is as follows:

```
<?php 
if($_REQUEST['page']==''){

        <form id=frm action='' method=post>
            <input type=hidden name=page value=calcs>
            ...
            <input type=submit id="submitButton" value='Get your instant quote'>
        </form>
}
else 
{   
    PACKAGE THE USER INPUT VIA XML AND SEND WITH A CURL COMMAND TO 3RD PARTY SERVER, RECEIVE REPLY IN XML.
    FROM REPLY EVALUATE MINIMUM PRICE QUOTE, ECHO TO PAGE, EMAIL WEBMASTER.    
}
?>
```

This works fine in my original HTML/PHP website, but I'm a noobie when it comes to Wordpress and I'm afraid I've bitten off more than I can chew :(((
In Wordpress I've made a page template page-form.php which resides in my theme folder. This file is very similar to the structure described above:

```
if($_REQUEST['page']==''){
    include 'template-parts/form.inc.php';
}
else 
{   
    PACKAGE THE USER INPUT VIA XML AND SEND WITH A CURL COMMAND TO 3RD PARTY SERVER, RECEIVE REPLY IN XML.
    FROM REPLY EVALUATE MINIMUM PRICE QUOTE, ECHO TO PAGE, EMAIL WEBMASTER.    
}
```

This Wordpress form displays correctly but when I fill it in and submit I land on a "Hello World" page with no price-quote and I recieve no email. form.inc.php is for all intents & purposes the same as the original form from the 1st version of the site.

Have I made some fundamental error in thinking I could transplant the structure straight to Wordpress? I have tried googling for similar issues but can't find anything, feels like I'm on the wrong path .... if anyone can give me a helping hand I'd be very grateful!

Comment: _“I land on a "Hello World" page”_ - with an empty form action, this submits to the same URL - so if you land somewhere completely different, my guess is it might probably have to do with this parameter name? Try and use a different one than `page`, and see if that changes anything.